# Motion tracking sometimes unstable when depth perception enabled

Tags: google-project-tango

Every so often (1 in 5/10 on average) when I start the Tango service configured with both motion tracking and depth perception enabled, the motion tracking is unstable right from the start and remains that way until I restart the Tango service. The instability appears as if Tango registers changes in device placement a fraction of a second too late, resulting in virtual content appears to "wobble" around when moving the device.

This effect occurs with motion tracking against start of service and area description frame. The pose information from Tango does not indicate errors or problematic states.

The device I observe it on is Lenovo Phab2 Pro. The yellowstone tablet doesn't have the problem. My project uses the Tango C library, Wasat release, version 1.44, September 2016). I notice the same issue with the Tango Java library, when for example enabling depth perception in the Java augmented reality sample app. The MeasureIt app in the Play store shows the same issue now and then.

I'm very curious to learn if this issue can be avoid, detector and/or recovered from.

Comment: One (failed) experiment I've tried to potentially mitigate this issue: Using the run time configuration option, I tried to set the depth frame rate to 0 right from the start (effectively disabling depth sensing) and only set it to 5 (current maximum) when needed. Unfortunately, the run time configuration of the depth frame rate does not seem to work, perhaps because not supported on Lenovo Phab2 Pro. (see also stackoverflow.com/questions/38006928/…)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Phab2 pro was running an outdated android build on my phone (PB2-690M_S000025_160706). Upgrading to build PB2-690Y_S000020_160924 solved the instability.